# Export csv to dynamodb using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

My requirement is i have 10 million csv records and i want to export the csv to DynamoDB?  Any one could you please help on this. 
And also is this possible to export tab separated values as well ?

Thanks,
in advance.

Comment: sample.csv          :::                                                                ORDERNO,DIRECTION,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
123456789,T,33.22,-101.23

Answer (score 5):

Convert your csv to json format and use **AWS BatchWriteItem DynamoDB API**

**Make sure to add your primary key data in the json**

```
import csv
import boto3

def convert_csv_to_json_list(file):
   items = []
   with open(file) as csvfile:
      reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
      for row in reader:
          data = {}
          data['temp'] = row['temp']
          #populate remaining fields here
          #................
          items.append(data)
   return items

def batch_write(items):
   dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
   db = dynamodb.Table('table-name')

   with db.batch_writer() as batch:
      for item in items:
         batch.put_item(Item=item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   json_data = convert_csv_to_json_list('file')
   batch_write(json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **AWS BatchWriteItem DynamoDB API** to perform batch inserts.

Iterate the file contents and insert them in batches.

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('sample_table')

with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for i in range(50):
        batch.put_item(
            Item={
                'ORDERNO': 'dummy',
                'DIRECTION': 'dummy',
                'LATITUDE': 'dummy',
                'LONGITUDE': 'dummy'
            }
        )
```

**Not so good approach but without any coding**

AWS Datapipeline has templates for doing data migration across different AWS services but for dynamodb, it can only load dynamodb backup data and not using csv.

Not straight forward approach, but you can do.

1. Upload the csv file to S3
2. Create a pipeline to copy data from S3 to an RDS instance(create one RDS mysql).
3. Use Database migration service to copy data from RDS to dynamodb.

Comment: I'm also using similar code, but its failing and getting below error:

Comment: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema

Comment: Code :
import boto3
import csv

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb','us-west-2')

def batch_write(table_name, rows):
    table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
    with table.batch_writer() as batch:
        for row in rows:
            batch.put_item(Item=row)
    return True

def read_csv(csv_file, list):
    rows = csv.DictReader(open(csv_file))
    for row in rows:
        list.append(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    table_name = 'emptest'
    file_name = 'test.csv'
    items = []

    read_csv(file_name, items)
    status = batch_write(table_name, items)

Comment: I'm using python 3.6